# SPARQL query for partial match of statement (contains)

Tags: sparql

I would like to know if there is a way in SPARQL to query for partial matches of statements. So if for example in the triple store I have an object containing "blablablaUsefulblablabla" I would like to be able to query for *Useful*, so I want to say that the statement "Useful" should be found, independent of what is before or after this statement.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I have an object containing "blablablaUsefulblablabla"

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you want the [**contains**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains) function.  E.g., on DBpedia:

```sql
select distinct ?city ?label where {
  ?city a dbpedia-owl:City ;
        rdfs:label ?label .
  filter contains(?label,"San")         #-- the important line
  filter langMatches(lang(?label),'en')
}
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fcity%20%3Flabel%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3ACity%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20contains%28%3Flabel%2C%22San%22%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks! That works. I assume there is no way to query for this directly, to save time to query?

If not, this is the best solution. Thanks

Comment: @robinaugy there is not in the standard, but some endpoints support property functions so that you can write things like `?label bif:contains "san"`. That can be helpful with endpoints that support text indexing.

Comment: Right, that could possibly be useful indeed. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Joshua or others, if I see it correctly this contains function is only for literals? Is there a way to do partial matches of URIs?

Comment: EDIT: Found it :) just need to do str(?s) instead of ?s then

Comment: Can you do something like using "or" for multiple filtering like filter contains(?label,"San" or "Ath" or "baa")

Comment: @GGEv Yes, you'd use [`in`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-in).  Something along the lines of `filter (?label in ("San", "Ath", "baa"))`.